# How to set related products view contextual filter to get its value from current product category id

Tags: views, commerce

I have build a Related Products view that supposed to show latest products which in the same category of the current product being viewed.

so I set a contextual filter for the category_id field, but couldn't find anyway to get the commerce product category id.

Drupal 8 / Commerce 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a block to display related products for the current viewed product by showing products from the same category.

To do that you can use the same steps used in the ['related article' tutorial](http://www.pixelwrapped.com/blog/related-articles-block-view-nodes-common-taxonomy-terms).

but first you have to add the ability to extract term id from product page (like the way it is extracted from node page), so you have to modify

```
core\modules\taxonomy\src\Plugin\views\argument_default\Tid.php
```

like this

include this namespace:

```
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductInterface;
```

look for:

```
    else {
      return implode($this->options['anyall'], array_keys($taxonomy));
    }
  }
```

replace with:

```
    else {
      return implode($this->options['anyall'], array_keys($taxonomy));
    }
  } elseif (($product = $this->routeMatch->getParameter('commerce_product')) && $product instanceof ProductInterface) {
    $taxonomy = [];
    foreach ($product->getFieldDefinitions() as $field) {
      if ($field->getType() == 'entity_reference' && $field->getSetting('target_type') == 'taxonomy_term') {
        $taxonomy_terms = $product->{$field->getName()}->referencedEntities();
        /** @var \Drupal\taxonomy\TermInterface $taxonomy_term */
        foreach ($taxonomy_terms as $taxonomy_term) {
          $taxonomy[$taxonomy_term->id()] = $taxonomy_term->bundle();
        }
      }
    }
    if (!empty($this->options['limit'])) {
      $tids = [];
      // filter by vocabulary
      foreach ($taxonomy as $tid => $vocab) {
        if (!empty($this->options['vids'][$vocab])) {
          $tids[] = $tid;
        }
      }
      return implode($this->options['anyall'], $tids);
    }
    // Return all tids.
    else {
      return implode($this->options['anyall'], array_keys($taxonomy));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve modifying core? Modifying core is bad practice and can lead to issues when core is updated.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I found a work around that doesn't involve modifying core, though its much less elegant and only really applicable if you only have a few terms. It also requires the twig_tweak module.
Basically I created a view block for each Related Products block filtered by one of the terms. Then in the twig template for the product view I created a bunch of conditionals for each term that checks for the term and then based on the result outputs the appropriate view: Like:

```
{% if 'term1' in product.field_my_term.0['#plain_text']  %}
  {{ drupal_view('related_products', 'block_1') }}
{% elseif 'term2' in product.field_my_term.0['#plain_text'] %}
  {{ drupal_view('related_products', 'block_2') }}
{% elseif 'term3' in product.field_my_term.0['#plain_text'] %}
  {{ drupal_view('related_products', 'block_3') }}
{% endif %}
```